# sharepoint designer 2010 doesn't see lists and libraries

Tags: sharepoint-designer

This morning, I was editing a custom new item form for one of my lists in SharePoint Designer 2010. After I came back from lunch, I opened my site again in Designer. Now, under "lists and libraries," it says "there are no items to show in this view." It's a Team Site, but none of the default lists or libraries appear in Designer, even though they still exist on the site itself.

I also can't connect to `http://your-site-name/_vti_bin/ListData.svc` via IE.

I've taken the following steps to attempt to resolve the issue:

- made sure the site and central admin are set to allow editing in Designer
- set Designer to "check if SharePoint is the default editor for all pages" on startup
- uninstalled and reinstalled Designer

Probably the real problem is not being able to connect to ListData.svc? What is wrong, and how can it have gone wrong since this morning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](http://www.thorntontechnical.com/tech/sharepoint/sharepoint-designer-2010-listlibrary-there-are-no-items-to-show-in-this-view-listdata-svc-woes) gave me the answer.

I had some broken lists on my site, which I was able to tell were broken by clicking on their links on the SharePoint site. Once I used PowerShell to delete the broken lists, everything worked properly again, and I was able to see my working lists in Designer.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://[yoursite]
$list = $web.Lists["Your Broken List"]
$list.Delete()
```